# Finding closure/interior of subset of function space

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, normed-spaces

Consider the subset $$A=\left\{f\in C(\Bbb R): |f(x)|< \frac{1}{1+|x|} \, \text{for all } x\in \Bbb R\right\}\subset \left\{f\in C(\Bbb R): \lim_{|x|\to \infty}f(x)=0 \right\}=X.$$

where $X$ is equipped with the operator norm. What is the closure and interior of $A$?

> My guess is that the **closure** of $A$ is the set $$B=\left\{f\in C(\Bbb R): |f(x)|\leqslant \frac{1}{1+|x|} \, \text{for all } x\in \Bbb R\right\}$$
>   and the **interior** is the set
>   $$C=\left\{f\in C(\Bbb R): \exists\epsilon>0 \text{ such that }|f(x)|< \frac{1}{1+|x|}-\epsilon \, \text{for all } x\in \Bbb R\right\}.$$

I'm fairly certain I got the closure right, but I'm unsure about the inerior.

Certainly $C$ is open and a subset of $A$, therefore, $C\subset \operatorname{int}A$. Does $\operatorname{int A}\subset C$ also hold?

Are my guesses correct?

Comment: $B$ is correct, $C$ is not. Indeed your $C$ is not well-defined: If $|x|$ is large, then $\frac{1}{1+|x|} -\epsilon <0$, so what can $|f(x)|$ be? (Instead, try to show that $A$ is open).

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you mean that $X$ is equipped with the $\sup$ norm $\Vert \cdot \Vert$ and define
$\mathcal{B}_r(g)=\{f \in X : \Vert f - g \Vert < r\}$ to be the open ball with center $g \in X$ and radius $r>0$.

The interior of $A$ is empty, because for every $g \in A$ there exists for every $r>0$ a function $f$ in $\mathcal{B}_r(g) \setminus A$.

Indeed, without loss of generality, we suppose $r < 1$ and define $x_r$, $\delta_{+}$ respectively $\delta_{-}$ by $\frac{1}{1+ x_r } = \frac{r}{2}$, $\delta_{+} = \frac{r}{2} - g(x_r)$ respectively $\delta_{-} = \frac{r}{2} - g(-x_r) $. It is then easy to check that the function $f$, defined by,

$f(x)=
\begin{cases}
\frac{c_{-}}{1 - x / 2} & \text{if $  x < - x_r$}, \\
g(x) -  \frac{x}{x_r} \delta_{-} & \text{if $ - x_r \leq x \leq 0 $},\\
g(x) +  \frac{x}{x_r} \delta_{+} & \text{if $0 \leq x < x_r$},\\
\frac{c_{+}}{1+ x / 2} & \text{if $  x_r \leq x$},
\end{cases}
$

satisfies the required properties, were $c_{+}$ is defined by $\frac{c_{+}}{1+ x_r /2}=\frac{1}{1+ x_r }$ and $c_{-}$ by $\frac{c_{-}}{1 - x_r /2}=\frac{1}{1- x_r }$to keep $f$ continuous.

Concerning the closure of $\bar{A}$ of $A$, as you say, it is given by the set $B$. Indeed,

$B \subset \bar{A}$ : let $b \in B$. Then, for every neighborhood $V$ of $b$ there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that $\mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(b) \subset V$. Let $k \in (\max(1- \epsilon,0), 1)$. Then $kb \in \mathcal{B}_{\epsilon}(b) \cap A$, because

$\Vert kb - b \Vert = (1-k) \Vert b \Vert < \epsilon \Vert b \Vert  \leq \epsilon \,\,$ and $\,\, \vert kb(x) \vert = k \vert b(x) \vert < \frac{1}{1+\vert x \vert}$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This shows that $b \in \bar{A}$.

$\bar{A} \subset B$ : let $a \in X \setminus B$. We need to show that $a \notin \bar{A}$. There exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ such that $ \vert a(y) \vert > \frac{1}{1+\vert y \vert}$. Let $r=\frac{1}{2}  \left( \vert a(y) \vert - \frac{1}{1+\vert y \vert} \right)$. Then $\mathcal{B}_r(a)$ does not intersect $A$, because for all $g \in \mathcal{B}_r(a)$ it is easily verified that $\vert g(y) \vert > \frac{1}{1+\vert y \vert}$. This shows that $a \notin \bar{A}$.

Answer (score -1):

According to your definition of $C$, $A\cap C =\emptyset$ ( if $f\in A$, $|f|$ eventually becomes smaller than $\epsilon$.)

Perhaps it makes more sense to consider the set:

$
C=\left\{ f\in A\,\,\, |\,\,\, \exists M>0 \,\,\,s.t.\,\,\, f(x)=0\,\,\, \forall |x| \geq M \right\}.
$